# Chuwi Corebook X 14' Intel i5-8259U Ubuntu battery support?

Tags: power-management, battery

I have just purchased a Chuwi Corebook X 14' Intel i5-8259U I installed Ubuntu 23.10. The battery is not recognized and so the battery display icon in not in the toolbar.

It appears that this might be a Bios issue.

I have seen on youtube that someone installed Ubuntu on a older Chuwi AeroBook Pro and the battery was recognized. Chuwi is shocking with support I thought to ask here.

Has anyone found a workaround?

Comment: See https://forum.chuwi.com/t/corebook-x-dual-boot-battery-indicator/33423

Comment: @DanielT thanks for the link, I have already read that post. Chuwi told me that their Bios doesn't support Linux, however the box my laptop came in brand new has a sticker with two operation option Windows or Linux go figure.